# Ruby program returns error "implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)"

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm trying to create a replica of Go Fish to help me learn more about arrays and hashes, and just how to go about structuring data. I'm on day two and have what looks to be much closer to the end goal. Keep in mind, I'm new to this. Anyway, here's the problem I'm running into:

> => gofish.rb:21:in `player_turn': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)

I understand why I'm getting the error, but I can't figure out how to use the .shift method without giving an index number. I would like to select which object to shift based on the value instead. So, if I correctly guess do you have an 'ace of spades', the card is removed from the cpu_hand array and is added to the my_hand array. With that said, I would just like to know the best way to go about this.

Here's my script:

```
card_values = ['ace', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven',
 'eight', 'nine', 'ten', 'jack', 'queen', 'king']
suits = ['spades', 'diamonds', 'hearts', 'clubs']

# creates array objects with every value and suit possible (full deck)
card_deck = card_values.product(suits).collect{|card, suit| "#{card} of #{suit}"}

def print_hand
  puts "Your hand: #{@my_hand.join(', ')}."
end

def player_turn
  puts "You go first!"
  puts "Do you have a..."
  puts @cpu_hand.join(', ')
  print "> "
  @card = $stdin.gets.chomp.downcase
  # if cpu has the card requested give it to the player and add to their array
    if @cpu_hand.include?(@card)
      puts "Ahhh...you got me. Here you go!"
      @my_hand.shift(@cpu_hand[@card]) # ****Here's the error(line:21) 
      print_hand
    else
      puts "Go fish!"
      @my_hand.shift(@card_deck[1])
      print_hand
    end
end


puts "There are #{card_deck.length} cards in this deck."
puts "Welcome to Go-Fish."
print "Your name please: "
player_name = $stdin.gets.chomp.capitalize

puts "Ok #{player_name}, lets get this deck shuffled..."
#sleep(1)
# shuffles card_deck using .shuffle method
card_deck = card_deck.shuffle
puts "Cards are perfectly shuffled!"
#sleep(1)
puts "Dealing cards..."
#sleep(1)
# assigns first 7 cards to user, removes from card_deck
@my_hand = Array.new
@my_hand = card_deck.shift(7)
# assigns next 7 cards to CPU, removes from card_deck
@cpu_hand = Array.new
@cpu_hand = card_deck.shift(7)

print_hand

until card_deck.length < 1 || @cpu_hand.length < 1 || @my_hand.length < 1
  player_turn
end

puts "GAME OVER!"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your error line,

```
@my_hand.shift(@cpu_hand[@card])
```

your crash is caused by attempting to index into the `@cpu_hand` array with a string (`@card`). The second issue is trying to call `shift` using a string as a parameter. Both of these need to be integers. `shift` removes the first element (or first `n` elements if an integer parameter is specified); this seems appropriate for taking an item from `card_deck`, but you'd want `push`, `unshift`, or `<<` to add an element to `@my_hand`. You'll also need a method to remove the specified card from `@cpu_hand`, `delete`:

```
if @cpu_hand.include?(@card)
  puts "Ahhh...you got me. Here you go!"
  @my_hand << @cpu_hand.delete(@card) # transfer a card from CPU to my hand
  print_hand
else
  puts "Go fish!"
  @my_hand << card_deck.shift # take the first card from the deck (could also be pop?)
  print_hand
end
```

However, `card_deck` is not a global like your other variables, so you'll need to pass it into the function and change the function header to `def player_turn card_deck`, or make it global. But making everything global is generally considered poor design because data can be mutated from anywhere, leading to difficult-to-find bugs. Consider writing classes such as `Hand` and `GoFish` (for example) that encapsulate all of the logic necessary to represent reusable pieces of your game.

I recommend taking a read through the [array docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html). You'll surely find some cool methods and learn a few tidbits.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, very helpful! Right now I'm really struggling with how to organize my code into classes. Do you know of any helpful resources for understanding how to "encapsulate all the logic necessary to represent reusable pieces" as you put it? I feel like at this point I'm just throwing together pieces of code and making things work little by little.  Also, would creating classes eliminate the need to create instance variables, is that what you meant? I thought glabal variables started with a $.

Comment: You're right: globals in Ruby are technically `$`-prefixed. But without a class, `@`-prefixed "instance" variables are visible inside any child function scope which is in a classical sense global. If you remove the `@`, these variables are local to the main function and you'd have to pass them as parameters. This would be better practice. But the next step after that is to group the functions logically: a `Deck` class might have `shuffle` and `draw` functions, for example, while a `GoFish` class might have a `cpu_turn` function.

Comment: Part of the confusion might be that `@`-prefixed variables are usually seen inside classes--you'll still need these variables, except their scope will be limited to the class and they'll be unique to each instance of the class you create. My suggestion is to start by removing all `@` variables from your code and pass all data as parameters. After that, you can refactor to classes if you wish. All this is entirely optional, but be warned that by not thinking in terms of design, you can wind up with a tangled mess that's hard to unwind (but that'd still be a worthwhile learning experience!).